# Функция MPI_Bcast не передает массив

Tags: c++, mpi

Изучаю параллельное программирование (MPI). При попытке передать массив всем процессам с помощью функции MPI_Bcast, сталкиваюсь с тем, что его получает только root-процесс. Не могу понять, почему. Есть идеи?

```
  #include "stdafx.h"

  #include "mpi.h"
  #include <time.h>
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;


   void Random1(double * A, int size)
  {
       srand(time(0));
       for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
       {
           do
           {
                 A[i] = rand()%20;
            }
            while (A[i]==0);
        }
   }


int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
double* B;

int Size, ProcNum, ProcRank;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcNum);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcRank);

if (ProcRank == 0)
{
    cout << "Input the dimension  ";
    cin >> Size;
    B = new double[Size];
    Random1(B, Size);
}
MPI_Bcast(&Size, 1, MPI_DOUBLE , 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&B, Size, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

cout << "Rank: "<<ProcRank<<"     B: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
{
    cout <<B[i]<<"  ";
}
cout << "\n\n";

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Во-первых, у вас почему-то `int Size` broadcast-ится как `MPI_DOUBLE`, а не `MPI_INT`.
- Во-вторых, если вы собрались broadcast-тить содержимое массива `B`, то

  ```
  MPI_Bcast(B, Size, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  ```

  Именно `B`, а не `&B`. То, что у вас сейчас написано, пытается broadcast значение указателя `B`, что уже бессмысленно само по себе, да еще и делается с неправильным размером.
- В-третьих, выделенная в root-процессе память для массива `B` не будет магическим образом сама по себе выделяться и в остальных процессах. Это ваша задача - выделять память для массива `B` в *каждом* процессе.

  То есть сначала вам надо broadcast размер массива `Size`, потом, после получения размера всеми процессами, выделить память под массив *в каждом процессе*, и затем уже делать broadcast на содержимое массива.